# Datetimepicker & Cocoon Showing multiple time toggle

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a nested form which is currently working, except that everytime I would add a nested form, it will display the calendar for each field on a click. Meaning, if there are 5 nested form each with a `Start` and `End` date, once the user clicks on the `calendar icon`, it will open 10 datetimepicker.

```
 <div class="input-group date datepicker">
      <%= f.text_field(:start, value: f.object.start ? f.object.start.strftime('%B %d, %Y') : nil, class: "form-control datetimepicker", data: {target: ".datetimepicker"}, placeholder: "#{t :From}", required: true) %>
      <div class="input-group-append" data-target=".datetimepicker" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
        <div class="input-group-text"><span class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <div class="input-group date datepicker">
      <%= f.text_field(:end, value: f.object.end ? f.object.end.strftime('%B %d, %Y') : nil, class: "form-control datetimepicker", data: {target: ".datetimepicker"}, placeholder: "#{t :End_time_or_until}", required: true) %>
      <div class="input-group-append" data-target=".datetimepicker" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
        <div class="input-group-text"><span class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </tr>
```

Anybody knows how to integrate this ?

I have this in my main form's JS :

```
 $(document).on('ready page:change', function() {
      insertedItem.find('.datepicker').datepicker()
      $('#invsessions').on('cocoon:after-insert', function() {
          $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
      })
  })
```

[image: Printscreen]

On this case, I add the nested form twice.

Comment: I posted the question 3 times, I thought many people had to go through this, as it is a quite common feature. But not getting any help at all.

Comment: f.text_field all have the same class of 'datetimepicker', all the data-targets are looking for the same class. This is why all the calendars are all showing at once.