# Turbolink - Fullcalendar only showing on reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have fullcalendar calendar that does not show unless I use turbolinks. But I would like not to use turbolink. Is there another way of loading the calendar.

My calendar.js looks like:

```
var initialize_calendar;
initialize_calendar = function() {
    $('.calendar').each(function(){
        var calendar = $(this);
        calendar.fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            lang: "en",
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true,
            events: '/events.json',

            select: function(start, end) {
                $.getScript('/events/new', function() {
                    $('#event_date_range').val(moment(start).format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm") + ' - ' + moment(end).format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm"));
                    date_range_picker();
                    $('.start_hidden').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));
                    $('.end_hidden').val(moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));
                });

                calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
            },

            eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
                event_data = {
                    event: {
                        id: event.id,
                        start: event.start.format(),
                        end: event.end.format()
                    }
                };
                // noinspection Annotator
                $.ajax({
                    url: event.update_url,
                    data: event_data,
                    type: 'PATCH'
                });
            },

            eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
                // noinspection Annotator
                $.getScript(event.show_url, function() {
                    $('#event_date_range').val(moment(event.start).format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm") + ' - ' + moment(event.end).format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm"));
                    date_range_picker();
                    $('.start_hidden').val(moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));
                    $('.end_hidden').val(moment(event.end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));
                });
            }
        });
    })
};
```

(I remove the following at the bottom because i am removing turbolinks from the app: `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', initialize_calendar);`
)

In my index.html.erb, i have :

```
  <div class="homepage_box_top_dashboard">
        <div class='calendar' id="calendar"></div>
      </div>
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to have something trigger your `initialize_calendar()` function to fire.

This *was* getting triggered by TurboLinks. Now you need something else to trigger it.

In plain speak:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', initialize_calendar);
```

means: "when the `turbolinks:load` event fires, call `initialize_calendar`"

Right now you are just telling the browser that `initialize_calendar` exists, but you're never turning it on.

You should be able to use this:

```
// Jquery
$(document).on('ready', initialize_calendar());
```

-or-

```
// JQuery shorthand
$(document).ready(initialize_calendar());
```

which means "when the `document:ready` event fires, call `initialize_calendar`"

-or-

```
// pure Javascript
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   initialize_calendar();
});
```

which means "when the `DOMContentLoaded` event fires, call `initialize_calendar`"

You always have to tell JavaScript when to do something. It doesn't have to be when the page loads.
For example, you could assign this action to a button:

```
$('#initialize_calendar_button').on('click', initialize_calendar);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: AMAZING! i put $(document).ready(initialize_calendar());
 in the view and it works now. Syncing to Heroku asap. Thank you so much!

Comment: In the view?? No! Put it at the very end of your `calendar.js` file. Keep your javascript out of your views!!

Comment: Ok I will do that. Just for my info, why should the javascript be kept out of the view ? is it for safety ?

Comment: Separating your concerns. Google "Rails unobtrusive JavaScript" for the rationale.

Comment: Excellent, i just read it. Thank you ! Very good way to share the knowledge.

Comment: By any chance, I have another issue that didn't catch people' attention: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58955564/datetimepicker-cocoon-showing-multiple-time-toggle, do you have an idea of a way to make it work please?